Couldn't connect to discord via discord Presence in VS Code
I have been downloaded Fedora Linux and Vs code by using Flathub and Discord with the same method, and Discord Presence doesn't work correctly. I think that it can be cause I downloaded it by using Flathub but i don't know.
